# Set Const Conditionally at compile time in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'd like to set the value of a const variable conditionally at Compile time.  I thought i could achieve this using vba compiler directives #If #Else etc. as below, but have been unsuccessful so far:

```
#If Environ("username") = "myusername" Then
    Public Const ErrorHandling As Boolean = False
#Else
    Public Const ErrorHandling As Boolean = True
#End If
```

When i run this code, im getting an error that the Environ variable is undefined.
Would something like this even be possible? Or do i just have to make my 'ErrorHandling' variable Public (not Const), and set it at the initialisation of my code?
 Thanks in advance,
cjk

Comment: Precompiler directives are evaluated *before compilation*; any function that's defined in a referenced type library (like `VBA.Interaction.Environ`) effectively doesn't exist *yet* at that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use constants in the conditional if statement. Either you set it in the VBAProject Properties, explained [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/02/16/conditional-compilation-arguments/), or in your code.

```
Sub TestIt()
#Const Errorhandling = False

    #If Errorhandling Then
        Debug.Print "Error on"
    #Else
        Debug.Print "Error off"
    #End If

End Sub
```

You find further documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-conditional-compilation) and a page on [pre-defined constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/compiler-constants)

**Update**: As Comintern pointed out correctly my statememt *only constants* is not completely true, see [section 5.6.16.2 of the language spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200188.aspx)

Comment: This is not *strictly* true.  There is a small subset of functions that can be used, as described in [section 5.6.16.2 of the language spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200188.aspx).

Comment: @Comintern: Thanks! I did not know that.

Comment: ok, thanks.  So my best option is probably to build my conditions into the initialisation of the code.  (Interesting how you can use the vba project properties for const declaration as well...)